# Does `dd` I/O read error alway indicate hardware failure?

Tags: backup, hard-disk, dd, io, block-device

I've purchased two 2TB drives. One has been formatted with an HFS+ (non-journaled) filesystem, and ~800GB of files written with `rsync`. I'm attempting to create a backup on the second with a basic `dd` block copy, but my operation repeatedly errors out reading the drive:

```
root@deb-server:/home/adm_user# dd if=/dev/sdb bs=32M | pv -s 2000G | dd of=/dev/sdc bs=32M
dd: error reading ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error              ]  0% ETA 28:24:40
75+1 records in
75+1 records out
2519728128 bytes (2.5 GB) copied2.35GiB 0:02:00 [19.9MiB/s] [>                                ]  0%             
, 120.663 s, 20.9 MB/s
0+36998 records in
0+36998 records out
2519728128 bytes (2.5 GB) copied, 125.599 s, 20.1 MB/s

root@deb-server:/home/adm_user# dd if=/dev/sdb bs=1M | pv -s 2000G | dd of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
dd: error reading ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error              ]  0% ETA 26:07:44
10333+1 records in
10333+1 records out
10.1GiB 0:07:57 [21.6MiB/s] [>                                ]  0%             
10835591168 bytes (11 GB) copied, 477.965 s, 22.7 MB/s
0+152209 records in
0+152209 records out
10835591168 bytes (11 GB) copied, 478.852 s, 22.6 MB/s

root@deb-server:/home/adm_user# dd if=/dev/sdb bs=1M | pv -s 2000G | dd of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
dd: error reading ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error              ]  0% ETA 25:55:35
13796+1 records in136KiB/s] [>                                ]  0% ETA 25:58:01
13796+1 records out
14466285568 bytes (14 GB) copied13.5GiB 0:10:34 [21.7MiB/s] [>                                ]  0%             
, 634.609 s, 22.8 MB/s
0+202579 records in
0+202579 records out
14466285568 bytes (14 GB) copied, 635.957 s, 22.7 MB/s

root@deb-server:/home/adm_user# dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc
dd: error reading ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error
186677728+0 records in
186677728+0 records out
95578996736 bytes (96 GB) copied, 13782 s, 6.9 MB/s

root@deb-server:/home/adm_user# dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc
dd: error reading ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error
167896800+0 records in
167896800+0 records out
85963161600 bytes (86 GB) copied, 12391.2 s, 6.9 MB/s
```

The errors never occur at the exact same spot, which indicates to me it's not hitting a bad sector on the disk. As you can see I've tried with more modest block sizes, and without `pv`, which seems to make more progress but still eventually errors out. I've snipped several more attempts, which all encounter the same error at different points.

I've read about a dozen forum threads and Stack Exchange posts on similar issues, and the conclusion always seems to be "`dd` I/O errors == disk failure". Others describing this problem are generally trying to recover old/known bad disks however, while hardware failure seems unlikely in this case: these are two brand new disks (a reputed model from HGST) and USB enclosures. What *is* quite likely are corrupt files on the disk: they were consolidated from about a dozen other disks of varying age and condition. From my understanding, filesystem or file errors are irrelevant to a block copy (also, no partitions were cloned to the disk).

I'm aware I can instruct `dd` to continue the copy with errors, and my next step is to do a (presumably much slower) filesystem-level backup with rsync, but first I'd like to get more certainty on whether this disk is good or not. I've considered a few other explanations, and am looking for guidance on how to diagnose this error. Other possibilities:

- Constrained resources: the Debian system has ~6.5GB of free RAM and 2.4 GB free disk space which seems adequate to me.
- USB bandwidth: this system has only USB 2.0 ports and both drives are connected through these (powered externally). Could `dd` simply error out because it's trying to read faster than the link allows?
- I also noticed some missing details in `hdparm` such as cache size. Is it possible to be missing some driver support for a disk?

  ```
  /dev/sdb:

  ATA device, with non-removable media
      Model Number:       Hitachi HUA723020ALA641                 
      Serial Number:      YGHJ32SD            
      Firmware Revision:  MK7OA840
      Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
  Standards:
      Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029)
      Supported: 8 7 6 5 
      Likely used: 8
  Configuration:
      Logical             max     current
      cylinders   16383   16383
      heads               16      16
      sectors/track       63      63
      --
      CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
      LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
      LBA48  user addressable sectors: 3907029168
      Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
      Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
      device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
      device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
      cache/buffer size  = unknown
      Form Factor: 3.5 inch
      Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
      [...]
  ```
- *Edit:* per recommendation I've checked `/var/log/messages`. It contains several sequences like below. Does this indicate the USB controller is crashing/failing and dropping the disk during read?

  ```
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.840187] usb 2-1.8: USB disconnect, device number 17
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847408] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847412] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb]  
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847413] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847414] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847415] Read(10): 28 00 00 5e 93 00 00 00 f0 00
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847423] quiet_error: 22 callbacks suppressed
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847473] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847474] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb]  
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847475] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847476] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
  Dec 11 10:15:26 deb-server kernel: [409707.847477] Read(10): 28 00 00 5e 93 f0 00 00 10 00
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.303411] usb 2-1.8: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.396916] usb 2-1.8: New USB device found, idVendor=2537, idProduct=1066
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.396921] usb 2-1.8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.396924] usb 2-1.8: Product: NS1066
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.396926] usb 2-1.8: Manufacturer: Norelsys
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.396928] usb 2-1.8: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDE
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.397214] usb-storage 2-1.8:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.397573] scsi20 : usb-storage 2-1.8:1.0
  Dec 11 10:15:27 deb-server kernel: [409708.984090]  sdc: sdc1
  Dec 11 10:15:28 deb-server kernel: [409709.916622] scsi 20:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HUA72302 A840 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
  Dec 11 10:15:28 deb-server kernel: [409709.916953] sd 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
  Dec 11 10:15:28 deb-server kernel: [409709.917560] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
  Dec 11 10:15:28 deb-server kernel: [409709.918568] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
  Dec 11 10:15:28 deb-server kernel: [409709.919565] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
  Dec 11 10:15:28 deb-server kernel: [409709.927455]  sdb: sdb1
  Dec 11 10:15:28 deb-server kernel: [409709.930559] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
  ```

Comment: Please take a look in `/var/log/messages` for any useful error messages.  Can also run `tail -f /var/log/messages` while you run the `dd`.

Comment: @DanArmstrong thank you for the tip, I've added what I found there. Currently I'm running another attempt, after switching the source and target disk enclosures. Curiously it's proceeded further than any of the others--will update tomorrow when I have the results.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by hardware failure, but yes, it is some kind of hardware issue.

It could be a transient one (power supply, overheating, or just a communication error), or a real hardware problem with the power supply, cables, harddisk (or on some controller chip, but it is more seldom).

Stop using `dd` and use `rescuedd` to avoid ruining the hardisk further, until you rule out a problem with the disk.

Comment: How will using `rescuedd` prevent "ruining further" the hardisk, or help in ruling out a disk problem?

Comment: ghostly_s: `dd` will try to read again broken sectors as he find them, but this could damage further the disk. `rescuedd` is created to preserve disk as much as possible, so when there is a problem, it will go away from that zone, and it will copy the rest, then it will return backward (on remaining sectors), etc. So it tries to recover as much as possible, and retry broken sectors are least as possible (only at the end).

Comment: Nothing about what I'm seeing here indicates bad sectors on the disk. I'm not following how this advice is relevant to the situation described.

Comment: I think the warning about `dd` with potentially broken HDD failure is a good one. Writing the advice as hard rule should be avoided, though. The `dd` is unsafe only if read or write head/arm is physically failing.

Comment: Also worth noting is that HDDs may suffer from random sector failures which often go unoticed except for S.M.A.R.T. data. If the disk surface has e.g. one bit surface imperfection from manufacturing, the disk firmware should notice that while writing the data and automatically remap the broken surface area to reserve sectors. Sometimes the imperfection causes the failing bit to change after-the-fact and this is why you sometimes get read errors from otherwise working drive. Once you write new data to that sector and the drive hopefully notices that the sector needs to be remapped, it's fine.

Comment: To locate this kind of random bit failures that change bits over time, you really want at least RAID5 to be able to identify the broken bit and run full RAID wide `check` or `scrub` action e.g. monthly. Note that drives usually report I/O error in case of random bit change so it may look identical to totally broken sector. A well implemented RAID will automatically try to fix the broken sector whenever one is detected.